# Can I integrate a Flash Professional SWF into Flash builder?

Tags: android, ios, flash-builder, flash

I am trying to make a game for mobile devices using flash professional and flash builder. I would like to make the gameplay components using flash professional. Then, I was hoping to export the swf file so that it could be imported into a flash builder project. The goal is to create the mobile menu system using flash builder and have it navigate into the gameplay swf file. Is this possible?

Sorry if this is a beginner question. I'm relatively new to Flash. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access symbols in the flash ide then an swc file is what you are looking for ;)

If you want to load the swf in your application then just use one of the many swf loaders you can find all over the web.

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/load-external-swf-swf.html